# BouncyCastle and Microsoft Cng ECDH secret key mismatch

Tags: .net, diffie-hellman, ecc

I'm trying to refactor some client-side code from BouncyCastle to Microsoft Cng. I've figured out how to convert key format(ECC key blobs) between them, but I couldn't calculate the same secret.

Currently, the client uses `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Agreement.ECDHBasicAgreement.CalculateAgreement()` to calculate the shared secret. The length of the shared secret depends on the curve(e.g, length of shared secrets for `SecP224k1` is 28 bytes).

Microsoft Cng(`System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellman`) provides several methods: `DeriveKeyMaterial`, `DeriveKeyFromHash`. However, none of them returns a result of 28 bytes. DeriveKeyFromHash returns bytes of 16/20/32/48/64 depends on HashAlgorithm, and DeriveKeyMaterial returns the same 32 bytes as DeriveKeyFromHash(SHA256).

Edit: Microsoft Cng's DeriveKey returns **Hashed** secret.

How to calculate the same secret using Microsoft Cng?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105010/extract-the-shared-secret-from-class-ecdiffiehellmancng

Comment: From this link, doesn't appear you can get the secret key out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Dave Satchell 's comment.

I go inside to .Net Framework source code. All `DeriveKey` calls `System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.UnsafeNativeMethods.NCryptDeriveKey`, which is P/Invoke of ncrypt.dll. You had to pass a key derivation function to [NCryptDeriveKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptderivekey)

For anyone who still want to calculate it without BouncyCastle or OpenSSL: I've calculate the shared secret by translating [python code](https://github.com/andreacorbellini/ecc/blob/master/scripts/ecdhe.py).
You may need to implement your own BigInteger or `using System.Numerics;`
Note: System.Numerics.BigInteger is little endian, and `%` (mod) works different in C# and Python.